# I want the old question layout back!

Tags: discussion, site-redesign

[Recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-site-home-pages-and-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-el?cb=1), Stack Exchange the company rolled out a new question layout.

I don't like this new layout. I want the old one back!

Comment: "bUT tHe SpaCiNG oN MoBIlE iS GreAT nOw" says the StackExchange reps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some CSS that puts the old layout back. Kinda. It's not perfect, but it'll do.

It also forces the numbers column on the left to be 200px wide. So it's not responsive. But if you're on a laptop or desktop, this shouldn't be an issue.

```
/* Fixes new question layout - kinda */

.s-post-summary {
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.s-post-summary--stats {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 1fr) minmax(0, 1fr) minmax(0, 1fr);
    width: 200px;
}

.s-post-summary--stats .s-post-summary--stats-item {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

.s-post-summary--stats .s-post-summary--stats-item.has-answers {
    border: none;
}

.s-post-summary--stats .s-post-summary--stats-item .svg-icon {
    display: none;
}

.s-post-summary--stats-item-number {
    display: block;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.s-post-summary--stats-item-unit {
    display: block;
}
```

So, how do you use this? Some browsers let you overwrite stylesheets with your own styles. Otherwise, you can use [Stylus Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne) for all your overwriting needs.

Comment: There's also the [Styl**ish** Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) which I use when doing such a thing.

Comment: @Scott Last I heard, Stylish was compromised.

Comment: Good to know @user3840170 thank heavens I pretty much never use it `:)` Removed from Chrome.

Comment: I use [Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha) for this.